# Multiple Conditions for Scheduled Reminder

Tags: scheduled-reminders

We have scheduled reminders working for us. However we need some that have multiple conditions. For example we have custom fields set up for an activity for recording wedding details and we need to send a scheduled reminder 3 months before the wedding date if the couple are not living in our parish.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think you can do this with Scheduled Reminders. The CiviRules extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) might be able to help you out. Some examples at https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/basic-example-introduction/

Having said so, I do not think there is a time comparison yet that will allow you to look forward as we have never encountered this. That will mean you will have to add this to CiviRules or have an expert do this for you. More information about extending CiviRules can be found here https://docs.civicrm.org/civirules/en/latest/create-your-own-introduction/.

Find yourself an expert on the CiviCRM home page if you need it, or let me know if you want me to take this on.

Answer (score 2):

You might be able to use a smart group to limit who the reminder goes to
https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/scheduled-reminders/#limiting-or-adding-to-your-recipient-list